# scss to styled-components conversion warning

Tags: reactjs, sass, styled-components

In a project, I was using SCSS, where I wrote this code and it works like a charm:

```
.container {
  padding: 0 1rem;
  .container {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

Now, I am starting another project using styled-components. So, there I am writing these styles:

```
const Container = styled.div`
  padding: 0 1rem;
  ${Container} {
    padding: 0;
  }
`;
```

Now I get a warning from compiler saying:

```
Container was used before it was defined.
```

**I want to ignore this warning without making any changes to eslint-file or disabling eslint for the line itself. I also don't want to use var instead of const.**

**Also, I am not willing to use a class on the div and then use it again here. (I would consider this as the last option if I do not find any better way of doing this).**

Is there any better way that I can change this code to ignore this warning?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question/issue it seems you want to reference the same container component. Use `&` to refer back to the main component.

[Using pseudoelements, pseudoselectors, and nesting](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#pseudoelements-pseudoselectors-and-nesting)

```
const Container = styled.div`
  padding: 0 1rem;
  & {
    padding: 0;
  }
`;
```